# Strip whitespace from multiindex issue - my code also removes the index names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some code to strip whitespace from the dataframe index values if it is a string:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: s.strip() if type(x) is str else x)
```

This seems to work fine for single index dataframes.  Unfortunately for multiindex dataframes it is removing the index names and replacing them with level_0, level_1 etc.

```
df.index.names
    FrozenList('Stag','Seq.','Block')

df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: s.strip() if type(x) is str else x)

df.index.names
    FrozenList('level_0','level_1','level_2')
```

I have a workaround below, but assume that there is a better/proper way.

```
indexNames = list(df.index.names)  # take a copy of the index names
indexNames
    FrozenList('Stag','Seq.','Block')

df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: s.strip() if type(x) is str else x)
df.index.names = indexNames  # reset the index names

df.index.names
    FrozenList('level_0','level_1','level_2')
```

I would like to know

1. what is happening to my original names
2. what is the best way to strip out whitespace from string index values that preserves the original index names.

I am new to python so the more hand holding the better.
Thanks

**EDIT TO POST SAMPLE CODE USING THE COMMENTS SUGGESTED TUPLE CHANGE**

Below is some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make a dataframe
iterables = [['bar', 'baz  ', 'foo  ', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']] #baz and foo have whitespace
myIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['Stag', 'Seq'])
df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=myIndex)

# Try and strip whitespace from the index values
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: tuple(xx.strip() if type(xx) is str else xx for xx in x))

# Now look at the index names
df.index.names
    FrozenList('None','None')
```

Comment: df.index.names gives you the names, not the values (use `df.index.levels`).

Comment: @coldspeed i'm sorry but I don't quite understand how to use your suggestion (I am very new to python)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post replicating code, with `s` in scope.  Based on what you've written, I assume this is a typo, but I'm not able to replicate your problem when I map on `lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) is str else x`.  Several points

- When you are mapping on a `MultiIndex`, the type of each element is a `tuple` and so your map function just becomes the identity since the condition  is  never met; nothing happens.
- On the other hand, if you map a function like `lambda x: tuple(xx.strip() if type(xx) is str else xx for xx in x)` you should get your desired result and the index names shouldn't change.
- Check out the documentation for [`pandas.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Index.map.html), and note that if your function returns a tuple with more than a single element, a `MultiIndex` will be used.

What version of `Pandas` are you using?  What I just said applies to at least `pandas.__version__ == 0.23.4`.

Comment: my pandas version is 0.20.3    You were right, the s is a typo.    I tried your idea of `df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: tuple(xx.strip() if type(xx) is str else xx for xx in x))` but I get `df.index.names` returning `FrozenList([None,None,None])`

Comment: Can't guarantee this  will work on `0.23.4`, and can't test if you don't post replicating code, but I think something like this would be okay: `df.index.map(lambda x: tuple(xx.strip() if type(xx) is str else xx for xx in x)).index.rename(df.index.names)`

Comment: I have added some test code to my original post.   BTW I tried running your suggestion on an online python site and it worked, so I think it is looking like it could be a version issue as they are running `0.23.3`   Is there a way to get this working on my version `0.20.3`??